# extract some data from an array php

Tags: php, arrays, extract

I use this code to know if in an array there are some value

```
 if(in_array("car", $parking))
 { $p_2="ok";  }
  else{ $p_2="KO"; }
```

Now suppose that my array is like this

```
 $parking=array("black","blue","car","white");
```

I know that in this array it could be some values like car or black because people put in this array through a form.

How can I extract the other data that aren't car o balck?

Comment: Please before asking check for official documentation http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php ... what exactly do you want? to show each value? (use foreach) to search for a specific value? (use in_array just like you've done)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you should use is [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) that returns the difference between two arrays.

```
$parking = array("black", "blue", "car", "white");
$diff    = array_diff($parking, array("black", "white"));

print_r($diff);
```

### Result

```
Array
(
    [1] => blue
    [2] => car
)
```